# How to give GET request parameters on load(string $filename)

Tags: php, xml, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to read an XML document using

```
load(string $filename)
```

such as

```
load("data.service.xml")
```

and it works. Now I want to read an XML document from a URL consisting of a GET request such as

```
load("https://e-activist.com/ea-dataservice/data.service?service=EaCampaignInfo&token=b818e721-48c6-4cc9-acc1-9da91071e294");
```

which doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it doesn't support HTTPS, it works with HTTP only. Doesn't make sense but that's how it is.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of `file_get_contents` within your `load`

```
load(file_get_contents("https://e-activist.com/ea-dataservice/data.service?service=EaCampaignInfo&token=b818e721-48c6-4cc9-acc1-9da91071e294"));
```

Make sure you have `HTTPS` wrapper on.

Answer (score 1):

Try the function : `simplexml_load_file()`

Example :

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file("https://e-activist.com/ea-dataservice/data.service?service=EaCampaignInfo&token=b818e721-48c6-4cc9-acc1-9da91071e294");
print_r($xml);
?>
```

Comment: Same problem. It doesn't work with URLs with GET requests it them.